# What causes enemies to reset?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I've been playing an Engineer recently, and although it can be fun to kite enemies instead of going toe-to-toe with them, I sometimes have a problem with enemies resetting before I have a chance to kill them. When this occurs, the enemy stops chasing you, returns to where they were when you first engaged them, and regenerates back to full health.

What causes an enemy to reset? How can I stay out of an enemy's range without resetting them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my own experience and programming skills, I would say that each monster probably has a `Pathing Algorithm` that tells him how to move, where to move for, what to avoid and the maximum range from its `Home Zone` it is allowed to move away, if it leaves its Home Zone, the mob will return to its zone and reset.

Also, what takes place here is time without receiving damage. If you run in front of a mob, it will follow you, but if it receives no damage in a matter of, i would say 8-9 seconds, it will stop chasing you.

There are two `Triggers` for the mob to stop attacking you and run back to its original coordinates : Time without receiving damage and Maximum walk range reached.

Numbers still needs testing but the `Triggers`are those, for sure, not taking in account the Underwater Environment which is sort of bugged causing monsters that are in battle with you face to face and in close range to sometimes, leave combat and regen full or half of its health for no good reason.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I've definitely had problems with underwater combat as well.